# How to add ISO images to UBCD4Win

Tags: diagnostic, ubcd

First off, I love UBCD4WIN. I have, however, found other utilities or ISO images I would like to include with my current CD. When I open the `menu.lst` file, I notice it seems to only allow .IMG and .IMA files. **Am I able to add .ISO files and just simply edit the `menu.lst` file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot find a more direct way to do it, you could use [**XBoot**](https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/) to make a top-level ISO list to choose from and have UBCD4WIN as one of the options.

I have used Xboot to make a CD with a whole load of useful bootdiscs in the past, and it worked well.

---

EDIT: I just noticed that there are [instructions for doing this on the UBCD4WIN.org website](http://www.ubcd4win.org/custom.htm#custommb), so you do not have to use XBoot.